# XHTTPRequest CORS errors on LTE vs WiFi

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

My web app makes multiple CORS calls using the XHTTPRequest object from a single method.  Over WiFi everything works fine.  Over an LTE network only some of the requests are successful, others show a 200 status but after 60 seconds I see an invalid response.

The issue is only present when making cross domain requests on LTE.  I can reproduce the error in Chrome and Safari.

All content is currently hosted in Amazon S3 and CORS configuration is set appropriately.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you added caching of your CORS response like max age?

Comment: Akash, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you added Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000 in your response? This header will cause preflight request to cache at client and till the age expires (in seconds), it will directly connect to server without preflight

Comment: Thanks Akash - this value was already set to a very large number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem won't have anything to do with your code.  Mobile networks are notoriously unreliable.  Plus, with CORS, there is often a pre-flight request, meaning that both requests would have to be successful for the request to work.

You will need to harden your application against connectivity failures, by properly handling these errors.  You will find the same problem for other unreliable networks as well.

Comment: Thanks Brad - I was fearful of this - do you have any suggestions for  how to handle these errors - I tried resending the failed requests to no avail.

Comment: OK - problem fixed - thanks for the insight Brad - My solution is to poll the xhr request object x ms after the call is made and if the request is not yet successful abort the request and make another.  The tricky part is defining the value of x - currently it is 500ms.

Comment: @huevosdeoro, 500ms is a very low timeout.  I would put it at 15 seconds.